Why ListView.builder hangs the app when an empty Container widget is returned from itemBuilder callback?
I just started learning Flutter and during the development, the app got stuck at Performing hot-reload.
I tried flutter clean, flutter pub get and reboot of the android emulator and then re-run the app. Now the app is stuck at Connecting to VM service.
After undoing my changes, it got resolved. So I traced my changes line by line and found that my incomplete code that returned an empty Container from ListView builder's callback is causing it. I could reproduce it in a clean project as follow:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container();
              }))),
    );
  }
}

Why does this happen? My guess is that it needs to return a Widget or a tree of Widgets that finally resolves to a Render Widget. But then, shouldn't it be somehow warned or errored if I cannot return Widgets that don't resolve to a Render Widget?
I have tried searching the existing Flutter issues and didn't find it.


The "itemCount" parameter in ListView.builder is missing, which is necessary to define the number of items the list should display.

The Container inside the itemBuilder is empty, meaning it has no height, width, or content, so nothing will be displayed.


Here's the updated version.

itemCount is added to the list view

ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10, // Added itemCount to define the number of items
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   return Container(
                    height: 50, // Defined a height for the container
                    color: Colors.blue, // Added color to make the container visible
                    child: Center(child: Text('Item $index')), // Added text to the container
                  );
                },
              )


Updated. try now

Thank you for the reply. But according to the two bullet points you mentioned, it should just cause a display showing nothing right? I don't see them being the cause of getting the app stuck on load. itemCount is also not mandatory when I checked the docs.

If itemCount is not specified, ListView.builder will keep calling the itemBuilder indefinitely. However, if you give a height to the container, it will generate a list that you can scroll infinitely. Not specifying both itemCount and a height for the container will cause an infinite loop. You can add a print() statement inside the itemBuilder to see this in action.

Yes, your reply is not precise but gave me the answer. When itemCount is not given, builder doesn't run indefinitely, but runs lazily with a limit of "until there is enough children for one scroll". Container tries to be as small as possible (found this behavior from A-E's answer) with no height and no child in it so it becomes a height-zero child.
Combination of these behaviors introduced the infinite loop of "Needs infinitely many height-zero Containers to fill the one-scroll space", causing app to be stuck. Can confirm by adding very tiny height to Container like 0.1.

Container with no child, no height, no width, no constraints, and the parent provides unbounded constraints (like scroll view widgets do), then Container tries to size as small as possible.
actually it collapses to zero size, Consequently, any widgets that rely on the presence of the Container for layout or spacing may also not appear as expected
which leads to white blank screen.
for more info about container go here

It makes sense. But, in the doc you linked, it says "If the widget has no child, no height, no width, no constraints, and the parent provides unbounded constraints, then Container tries to size as small as possible." not as big as possible.

I had this issue, spent way too long debugging it. Absolutely no explanation.
From my testing, returning ANYTHING except an empty Container seems to work just fine, even null. No error messages, just hangs the application if an empty Container is returned.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
